# Animated underline Css Navigation menu blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I want to underline the hover for page buttons.
How can I adapt these codes to my blogger Page list?

```css
.top-nav .PageList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  
  & > li {
    display: inline-block;
    
    & ~ li {
      margin-left: 1em;
    }
  }
  
  a {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    &:focus,
    &:hover {
      color: #CF000F;
      
      &:after {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    &:after {
      margin: 0 auto;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid;
      border-top-color: inherit;
      width: 0%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .25s;
```

Here is my blog

https://ubuntuvpssupport.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

Blogger provides theme settings. Go to theme designer and there go to the tab called "Advanced" in the left panel. In this Advanced tab, last option is "Add css" where you can add any custom styles.

You can add below style there.

`a:hover, .action-link:hover {text-decoration: underline}`

You can also refer guide here
https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en

Hope it helps you:)